# Compile time code generation based on the size of template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have the following piece of code:

```
template<typename T, typename... args>
void func(const my_type<T, args...>& set, std::ofstream t_print, std::ofstream args_print) {
        t_print << set.get_t() << std::endl;

        if (sizeof...(args) > 0) 
            data << set.get_args() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The evaluation of the `if` condition is deferred to run time, and the compiler generates code for the body of the `if`. My question is if there is a way to make that the compiler does not generate code in case of `sizeof...(args) == 0`, without the use of the template specialization technique. Is there any workaround in modern C++?

Comment: "make that the compiler does not generate code in case of `sizeof...(args) == 0`" If the (optimized) version generates code for that, file a bug with your vendor.

Comment: Sorry I generated the code for debug configuration.

Comment: You *can* use polymorphic lambdas to achieve some sort of inline tag-dispatch: [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/616a698807b2148f). If you look at the [generated code](https://godbolt.org/g/20EFoS), even at -O0 the "branch" never taken does not appear. Though I imagine both human readers and the compiler have an easier time with the regular tag dispatch or SFINAE approach :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `std::enable_if`:

```
template <typename T, typename ... ARGS>
std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(ARGS)>0)> func(...) { ... }
```

In this case, `func` will only appear as part of the overload set if the size of `ARGS...` is greater than 0.  However, if the size is zero, you will be missing a function from your overload set.  Maybe that's want you want, though.

Comment: I would have to add an overload for the case when size of ARGS... is 0, that is exactly what I am asking if it is possible to avoid, even in new C++ standards. As T.C. commented, in the optimized version the compiler does not generate that part of the code.

Comment: Yes, you either need to specify an overload set that can handle the valid use cases.  Or/and you need to rely on compile-time optimization.  Both are perfectly acceptable and are different ways of generating optimized code.  Modern C++ provides simpler means to achieve the former, but it does not remove the basic need that a function definition must be available for the arguments with which it is called.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pragmatic, non-obfuscated trick for this, which consist of having the pack only later

```
template<typename T, typename arg, typename... args>
void func(const my_type<T, arg, args...>& set, std::ofstream t_print, std::ofstream args_print) {
    t_print << set.get_t() << std::endl;
    data << set.get_args() << std::endl;
}
```

However if you consider doing this as an "optimization", just stop right away. You should then also be worried about your use of C++ and program directly in assembly. Oh stop, you should first of all read the intel developer manual to know your CPU better than your compiler's code generation for this to pay off.

Bottom line - just don't worry about performance at this level. "No optimizations enabled" doesn't mean "Dumb code generation". Any half-decent compilers won't emit an `if(0) ...` even with optimizations disabled.